# how can manual create a ODataQueryOptions on .ashx

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

i would like to reconstruction my last project.
in past, i did't use any Web API.
can i just use the ODataQueryOptions to do $filter, $orderby , $top ,$skip 
for my query in my own handler.ashx ? 
some thing like.

```
var option = new ODataQueryOptions(request.params);
var query = option.ApplyTo(db.products);
```

Comment: Yes you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataqueryoptions(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Based on sfuqua's answer above I made my own helper class that builds OdataQueryOptions class based on Odata Uri:

```c#
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Query;

namespace OdataHelpers
{
    public static class ODataBuilder<T>
    {
        public static ODataQueryOptions<T> BuildOptions(string oDataUri)
        {
            var baseUri = "";
            var odUri = "";
            var spl = oDataUri.Split('?');
            if (spl.Count() == 0)
                odUri = spl[0];
            else
            {
                baseUri = spl[0];
                odUri = spl[1];
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUri))
                baseUri = "http://localhost/api/" + typeof(T).Name;
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, baseUri + "?" + oDataUri.Replace("?", ""));
            var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.AddEntity(typeof(T));
            var edmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
            var oDataQueryContext = new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, typeof(T));
            return new ODataQueryOptions<T>(oDataQueryContext, request);
        }
    }
}
```

Example use:

```c#
var OdataStuff = ODataBuilder<CustomerIntView>.BuildOptions("$orderby=Id");
```

Comment: I have added this implementation to my ReverseOdataUriParser lib:
https://github.com/Svakinn/ReverseOdataUriMapper

Comment: Finally!! This 1) works and 2) doesn't require a massive implementation which uses the database entities. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to port the approach to .Net 5 and it does not work. Do you have a similar example for .Net 5.

Comment: This one should be the answer. For me it was excellent for UnitTesting my services and endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is by manually constructing the request URI and setting that in the request parameter of the `ODataQueryOptions` constructor. So this may not be precisely what the original poster was looking for (question needed some clarification).

In my case I have a unit test, and I wanted to validate that the odata options were being applied to my queryable object. In the following sample code, assume that you are testing a `ProductController` that has a ProductName field in it.

```cs
// Manually set an OData query parameter
const string restUrl = "http://localhost/api/product?$orderby=ProductName";

// Need to construct an HTTP Context and a Request, then inject them into the controller
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, restUrl);
var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(WebApiConfig.DefaultRouteName, "api/{controller}/{id}");
var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Product" } });

var controller = new ProductController()
{
    Request = request,
    ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request),
    Url = new UrlHelper(request)
};

// Build up the OData query parameters
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.AddEntity(typeof(Product));
var edmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
var oDataQueryContext = new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, typeof(Product));
var oDataQueryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions<Product>(oDataQueryContext, _controller.Request);

// Finally, call the controller
var result = controller.Get(oDataQueryOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do think you can if you can constructor an instance of `ODataQueryOptions`.

But, What's this:

```
var option = new ODataQueryOptions(request.params);
```

Web API doesn't provide such constructor. Is it your own implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on Svakinn's answer for .NET 8:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;

namespace ODataHelper;

public static class ODataHelper
{
    // oDataQuery has to start with $filter=...
    public static ODataQueryOptions BuildOptions<T>(string oDataQuery)
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            Request =
            {
                Method = "POST",
                Scheme = "http",
                Host = new HostString("localhost"),
                ContentType = "application/json",
                Query = new QueryCollection(QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(oDataQuery))
            }
        };
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write("{}");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        httpContext.Request.Body = stream;
        var request = httpContext.Request;

        var type = typeof(T);

        var odataPath = request.ODataFeature().Path;
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.AddEntityType(typeof(T));
        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
        var oDataQueryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, type, odataPath);

        return new ODataQueryOptions<T>(oDataQueryContext, request);
    }
}
```